# Electrostatics Charges in Stable or Unstable Equilibrium or Numerical - How to solve this analytically?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, equilibrium

[image: Figure associated with the Problem]

In this problem we can have a negative charge to the Right of +q and Positive Charge to the left of -3q for the Purpose of equilibrium of all the Three Charges. Now we know that for stable Equilibrium the restoring force is required when any of the charge is moved from its state. For this problem which condition is the situation of Stable Equilibrium ? Your help will be highly appreciated. The Magnitude of the Third charge is unknown as per the problem statement so a a generic answer is expected.

Comment: stable equilibrium means all the charges in system should remain at rest if a third charge is placed .

Comment: Thanks. Would the definition of stable Equilibrium also include the tendency  each of the charge to return back to its original position upon being displaced ? i.e Positive static Equilibrium. If I take a Positive Charge +Q to the Right of +q at a distance y , assume the distance between the given charges to be  x  I get y=-1.366x i,e +Q should be to the left of -3q. Is this enough for stability or do i need to prove that its positive static Equilibrium ?

Comment: For stable vs unstable see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_equilibrium). If you put a positive charge to the left of the $-3q$, why should this config be stable. Don't try to "do the math", but try to thinks about the setup.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. I did it Analytically. maverick and Semi -Highly appreciate your prompt help.